# How to prevent dangling pointers/junk in c?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm new to C and haven't really grasped when C decides to free an object and when it decides to keep an object.

heap_t is pointer to a struct heap.

```
heap_t create_heap(){
    heap_t h_t = (heap_t)malloc(sizeof(heap));
    h_t->it = 0;
    h_t->len = 10;
    h_t->arr = (token_t)calloc(10, sizeof(token));
    //call below a couple of times to fill up arr
    app_heap(h_t, ENUM, "enum", 1);
    return h_t;
}
```

putting h_t through

```
int app_heap(heap_t h, enum symbol s, char* word, int line){
    int it = h->it;
    int len = h->len;

    if (it + 1 < len ){
        token temp;
        h->arr[it] = temp;
        h->arr[it].sym = s;
        h->arr[it].word = word;
        h->arr[it].line = line;
        h->it = it + 1;
        printf(h->arr[it].word);
        return 1;
    } else {
        h->len = len*2;
        h->arr = realloc(h->arr, len*2);
        return app_heap(h, s, word, line);
    }

}
```

Why does my h_t->arr fill up with junk and eventually I get a segmentation fault? How do I fix this?  Any C coding tips/styles to avoid stuff like this?

Comment: What is "token"?  For what it's worth, I don't think you need to declare token temp and assign it to h->arr[it].  Given that h->arr is a token pointer and you have the memory for it, h->arr[it] is already a token struct.

Comment: When you say it "fills up with junk", how do you know this?  What are the symptoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to answer your question about the crash, I think the reason you are getting segmentation fault is that you fail to multiply `len` by `sizeof(token)` in the call to `realloc`. You end up writing past the end of the block that has been allocated, eventually triggering a segfault.

As far as "deciding to free an object and when [...] to keep an object" goes, C does not decide any of it for you: it simply does it when you tell it to by calling `free`, without asking you any further questions. This "obedience" ends up costing you sometimes, because you can accidentally free something you still need. It is a good idea to NULL out the pointer, to improve your chance of catching the issue faster (unfortunately, this is not enough to eliminate the problem altogether, because of shared pointers).

```
free(h->arr);
h -> arr = NULL; // Doing this is a good practice
```

To summarize, managing memory in C is a tedious task that requires a lot of thinking and discipline. You need to check the result of every allocation call to see if it has failed, and perform many auxiliary tasks when it does.

Answer (score 1):

C does not "decide" anything, if you have allocated something yourself with an explicit call to e.g. `malloc()`, it will stay allocated until you `free()` it (or until the program terminates, typically).

I think this:

```
   token temp;
   h->arr[it] = temp;
   h->arr[it].sym = s;
   /* more accesses */
```

is very weird, the first two lines don't do anything sensible.

As pointed out by [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8896190/28169), you're failing to scale the re-allocation into bytes, which will cause dramatic shrinkage of the array when it tries to grow, and corrupt it totally.

- You shouldn't cast the return values of `malloc()` and `realloc()`, in C.
- Remember that `realloc()` might fail, in which case you will lose your pointer if you overwrite it like you do.
- Lots of repetition in your code, i.e. `realloc(h->arr, len*2)` instead of `realloc(h->arr, h->len * sizeof *h->arr)` and so on.

Note how the last bullet point also fixes the `realloc()` scaling bug mentioned above.

Comment: Don't forget to multiply with 2 to actually grow the array.

Answer (score 0):

You're not reallocating to the proper size, the realloc statement needs to be:

```
    realloc(h->arr, sizeof(token) * len*2);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(Or perhaps better `realloc(h->arr, sizeof *h->arr * h->h_len);`)

In C, you are responsible to free the memory you allocate. You have to free() the memory you've malloc/calloc/realloc'ed when it's suitable to do so. The C runtime never frees anything, except when the program has terminated(some more esoteric systems might not release the memory even then).

Also, try to be consistent, the general form for allocating is always `T *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo)`, and dont duplicate stuff.

e.g.

```
h_t->arr = (token_t)calloc(10, sizeof(token));
            ^^^^^^^^       ^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

1. Don't cast the return value of malloc in C. It's unncessesary and might hide a serious compiler warning and bug if you forget to include stdlib.h
2. the cast is token_t but the sizeof applies to token, why are they different, and are they the same type as *h_t->arr ?
3. You already have the magic 10 value, use h_t->len
4. If you ever change the type of h_t->arr, you have to remember to change the sizeof(..)

So make this

```
  h_t->arr = calloc(h_t->len, sizeof *h_t->arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two main problems in creating dangling pointers in C are the not assigning 
NULL to a pointer after freeing its allocated memory, and shared pointers.

There is a solution to the first problem, of automatically nulling out the pointer.

```
void SaferFree(void *AFree[])
{
    free(AFree[0]);
    AFree[0] = NULL;
}
```

The caller, instead calling

```
free(p);
```

will call

```
SaferFree(&p);
```

In respect to the second and harder to be siolved issue:
[The rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) says:

**If you need to explicitly declare either the destructor, copy constructor or copy assignment operator yourself, you probably need to explicitly declare all three of them.**

Sharing a pointer in C is simply copying it (copy assignment). It means that using the rule of three (or the general rule of 0)
when programming in C obliges the programmer to supply a way to construct and especially destruct such an assignment, which is possible, but not an 
easy task especially when C does not supply a descructor that is implicitly activated as in C++.